# Filter messages in AWS SNS subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I created a SNS subscription and started receiving bunch of emails

I'm interested in receiving only following emails:

All emails with `New Compliance Change Record` or `complianceType` in message body

I found this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html, according to this i need to specify value for `complianceType` which is not what i want.

I need to get any email with with `New Compliance Change Record` or `complianceType` in message body

```
New Compliance Change Record:
----------------------------
{
"awsAccountId": "123456789",
"configRuleName": "encrypted-volumes",
"configRuleARN": "arn:aws:config:us-east-1:279052847476:config-rule/config-rule-3sovvx",
"resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
"resourceId": "vol-0f4f07ce39ca10b26",
"awsRegion": "us-east-1",
"newEvaluationResult": {
"evaluationResultIdentifier": {
"evaluationResultQualifier": {
"configRuleName": "encrypted-volumes",
"resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
"resourceId": "vol-0f4f07ce39ca10b26"
},
"orderingTimestamp": "2018-06-12T00:31:39.624Z"
},
"complianceType": "NON_COMPLIANT",
"resultRecordedTime": "2018-06-12T00:31:43.838Z",
"configRuleInvokedTime": "2018-06-12T00:31:43.595Z",
"annotation": null,
"resultToken": null
},
```

Tried this:

```
{
"complianceType" : {"Type":"String","Value":"*"}
}
```

but got error from picture[image]

managed to set this filter though, but not sure is it correct

```
{
"complianceType" :["NON_COMPLIANT","COMPLIANT"]
}
```

Comment: From your link: *"When you publish a message to a topic, Amazon SNS compares the **message attributes** to the attributes in the filter policy for each of the topic's subscriptions. If there is a match between the attributes, Amazon SNS sends the message to the subscriber."* What you have shown is the message *body* -- not the [message attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html) that are the subject of SNS filters.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot, i tried steps from link above but i need to specify message, not sure what to put there

Comment: SNS filters only work for message attributes.  Unless I am overlooking something, these events will need to be processed by a Lambda function, so that you can examine the body.  You can then copy specific values into the message attributes and send them back to SNS where they can be filtered.

Comment: uh !, no idea how to do that, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use payload-based message filtering to address your need: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/